# Rails Mailer: Each do loop in Mailer View doesn't show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, html-email, actionmailer

I am implementing email (sendgrid in production, letter_opener in development) for my Rails 5 app but can't get my Mailer view to show the results of a loop.

My mailer.html.erb code is:

```
    Hello <%=@order.customer_name %>

    <%@order.carted_activities.each do |cartact|%>  
    <%=cartact.supplier_activity_option.supplier_activity.activity.name %>  
    <%=cartact.supplier_activity_option.option_name %> 
    <% end %>

    Total: <%=number_to_currency @order.total_price %>
```

Everything outside of the loop shows but everything inside the loop is invisible. If instead of the each do loop I just put <%=@order.carted_activities%>, it does retrieve the record in the database and show

> `#<CartedActivity::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007ffe3144e6c0>.`

So the problem just seems to be the loop - any ideas how I can resolve this please??

Comment: Are you sure it's not just an **empty** collection?

Comment: It isn't unfortunately - have double checked it on console!

Comment: What does `<%= @order.carted_activities.inspect %>` display if you add it to the view?

Comment: @Iceman it shows #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Comment: @TomLord Actually I suspect you may be right - when I run the mailer code to execute after_create, the collection may be empty. But when I run the mailer code to execute after_commit, the collection shows up - so I guess I'll do it after_commit then! After_commit does strangely give me the issue of having two identical emails being sent out at the same time for some reason but that's probably something for another question

Comment: `after_create`? `after_commit`? This is all information missing from your original question. I'd need to see a [mcve] of your problem to understand/assist further. For the time being, my original suspicion was correct: The array is empty, therefore `array.each { ... }` never yields anything.